# Lubuntu wireless driver problems (Lubuntu 12.04, Realtek RTL8190)

Tags: 12.04, wireless, drivers, lubuntu, realtek

I have freshly installed Lubuntu on a friends PC, but I am unable to get the wireless working. There is no option to scan for networks and adding one manually does nothing.

```
$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: NetXtreme BCM5751 Gigabit Ethernet PCI Express
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 01
       serial: 00:12:3f:76:65:05
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm vpd msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=tg3 driverversion=3.121 duplex=full firmware=5751-v3.44a ip=192.168.1.103 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:17 memory:f7ef0000-f7efffff
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: RTL8190 802.11n Wireless LAN
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 5
       bus info: pci@0000:05:05.0
       version: 00
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=64 maxlatency=64 mingnt=32
       resources: ioport:dc00(size=256) memory:f7dff000-f7dfffff
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I found the same issue with Lubuntu 32Bit. What I did was attach an ethernet cable and run `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get install -f`.

By running `ifconfig wlan0 up` you will enable WiFi and then test with `iwlist wlan0 scan`to see if it recognizes any Networks; test with Ethernet and WiFi. When you are aware of which wireless network you want to connect to run `iwconfig wlan0 essid NETWORK_ID key s:WIRELESS_KEY`: replace NETWORK_ID with the name (essid) of the nework and WIRELESS_KEY with the network passcode.

I cannot add my source as I went looking when I had this issue. Please let me know if this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your reply. `ifconfig wlan0 up` does not work, with the following message: _wlan0: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device_. I have tried to install the drivers, but this did not help either.